# SQL insert only table, how to select only newest entries

Tags: mysql, sql

I've created an insert only table for the purpose of speed and maintaining a history. It's structure is very generic, and is as follows:

```
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `user_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `property` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `value` longblob NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

It's simply a key/value table with a user_id assigned to it. This approach has its advantages as not all users have the same properties, so fields aren't wasted in a table. Also, it allows for a rolling log of changes, since I can see every change to a particular property ever made by a user.

Now, since no deletes or updates ever occur in this table, I can assume that the greatest id will always be the newest entry.

However, I want to select multiple properties at once, for example 'address1', 'address2', 'city', 'state', and I want each to be the entry of it's type with the highest id.

So, if they have changed their 'state' property 8 times, and 'city' property 4 times, then I'd only want a SELECT to return the latest of each (1 state and 1 city).

I'm not sure this can even be done efficiently with this type of a table, so I'm open to different table approaches.

Please, let me know if I need to produce anymore information or clarify my question better.

===
I tried the following, but, there could be 3 rows of 'address1' changes after the last 'address2' change. Perhaps using a GROUP BY will work?

`SELECT property, value FROM kvtable WHERE user_id = 1 AND (property = 'address1' OR property = 'address2') ORDER BY id`

Comment: "*Now, since no deletes or updates ever occur in this table, I can assume that the greatest id will always be the newest entry*" - no you can't.  What if one `INSERT` specifies an explicit `id` of ***`x`***, then later one specifies explicit `id` of ***`y`*** `<` ***`x`***?

Comment: It is auto increment, and shouldn't explicitly be defined. Is that still a safe assumption? I could add a date column.

Comment: Just because a column is defined `AUTO_INCREMENT` does not prevent a user providing an explicit value during `INSERT` - it merely sets an incremented value if no explicit value is provided.  Generally speaking, a timestamp column is safer; however, if you are in full control of every `INSERT` operation and can ensure that explicit `id` are not provided, I *think* it's safe to work on the assumption that `id` will be strictly increasing by time of insert.

Comment: Fair enough, thanks for the advice. Adding a timestamp field to a table that will hold an estimate 100 million records in a couple years time (I think this estimate is a bit verbose to say the least) would add 400MB. Would abandoning the auto increment id, and using an aggregate key of user_id, property, and timestamp work equally as well?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming your ids are incremental integers *and you have not manually specified them out of order*, you can do this with a few `MAX()` aggregates in a subquery.  The point of the subquery is to return the latest entry per property name, per user.  That is joined against the whole table to pull in the associated property values.  Essentially, the subquery discards all rows which don't have a max(id) per group.

```
SELECT kvtable.* 
FROM
  kvtable
  JOIN (
    SELECT
      MAX(id) AS id,
      user_id,
      property
    FROM kvtable
    /* optionally limit by user_id */
    WHERE user_id = <someuser>
    GROUP BY user_id, property
  ) maxids ON kvtable.id = maxids.id
```

Comment: This seems to do the job. Now if I want to restrict it to users of a specified id, I would append that do the JOIN ON statement as `ON properties_table.id = maxids.id AND properties_table.user_id = 1` for example?

Comment: @crush Yes, in the ON clause or you could add a `WHERE` clause to the subquery.

Comment: Great. This seems efficient enough at the moment anyways. Thanks for the help!

Comment: an index on `(user_id, property)` will help performance (it will be used by the subquery).

Comment: ypercube, thanks for the suggestion. I will try it out! What type of index should it be? BTREE, HASH, or RTREE? I assumed HASH